# Outlook 2016 Add In: How to create ribbon for group item in VSTO

Tags: email, outlook, vsto, ribbon

i want to edit the ribbon for group items like "today", "yesterday", "last week"... for Outlook 2016 using VSTO.

[This is the item i want to edit.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7miC2.png)

I dont know which ID I have to use.
This is an example for editing the ribbon on an Email item:

```
<contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuMailItem">
  <dynamicMenu id="ShowPath" label= "Wo bin ich?" getContent="showPath"/>
</contextMenu>
```

Regards,
Fabian